# c# List<Dictionary<string,string>> add unique dictionaries

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> items = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

foreach (var group in groupedItems)
{

    foreach (var item in group)
    {
         Dictionary<string, string> newItem = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         newItem.Add("name", item.Name);
         newItem.Add("value", item.Value);
    }
 }

items.Add(newItem);
```

Basically when I loop through the grouped items, I create a Dictionary where the key is the item.Name and value is item.Value. In a grouped case, this will result in duplicate dictionaries to the list.

How can I avoid adding duplicate Dictionary to this List?

I have a foreach loop and I want to add some items once.

Comment: Define duplicate dictionary first.

Comment: I made an edit to the question

Comment: Does it work if you use a HashSet<Dictionarystring, string>> instead of a List?

Comment: User, your update won't compile, there isn't a `groupedItems` and `newItem` is used outside of its scope

Comment: I know but it doesnt explain your definition of duplicate dictionaries. Is a dictionary a duplicate if any of the keys is in one of the other dictonary's keys? Or must all keys be equal or must all keys  and all values equal or must it be the same reference ....?

Comment: @mboldt: HashSet doesn't work.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile

Comment: Of course it doesn't compile because the groupedItems is Linq grouped by query which is not present in the above code.

Comment: @user2818430 But in this case item is an IGrouping<string, string> so it's got a Key and implements IEnumerable<string> but it doesn't have a Name or a Value

Comment: @vc: True that. My mistake. I made a change to the question. So there are 2 foreach. One for each group in groupedItems and second for each item in group.

Comment: What is `gropuedItems`?

Comment: @user2818430 OK I see, so what you're actually after is groupedItems.Select(group => group.ToDictionary(item => item.Name, item => item.Value)).ToList() which produces a dictionary per group entry. But then what do you mean by duplicate dictionary?

Comment: @vc74: Exactly it produces the dictionary per group entry. Now foreach group the same dictionary is produced and inserted to the list which results in duplicate dictionary within the list.

Comment: @user2818430 Can you post your linq GroupBy code?

Answer (score 3):

First thing that comes to mind would be to create your own class which `extends` `Dictionary<string, string>` and implement your own version of `GetHashCode()` and `Equals`:

```
public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public override int GetHashCode() 
    {
        ...
    }

    public override bool Equals(object source) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Within the `Equals` you implement your equality mechanism, and in `GetHashCode` you implement a mechanism which yields the same numeric value for two dictionaries which are the same, according to your equality criteria.

Then, instead of a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, you use a `HashSet<MyDictionary>`. Since sets do not allow duplicates, you should end up with a collection of unique dictionary collections.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this in this way:

I created a new dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> control = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

And then I just do like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> newItem = new Dictionary<string, string>();
newItem.Add("name", item.Name);
newItem.Add("value", item.Value);

if (!control.ContainsKey(item.Name))
{
   control.Add(item.Name);
   items.Add(newItem);
}
```

Comment: What is "items" referring to here?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `EqualityComparer` to determine if two dictionaries are equal:

```
class EqualityComparer<Dictionary<string, string>> : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string, string>>
{

    public bool Equals(Dictionary<string, string> x, Dictionary<string, string> y)
    {
        // your code here
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<string, string> obj)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Now you may use this comparer within a check for existance of a new item:

```
foreach (var g in groupedItems)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> newItem = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach(var item in g) 
    {
        newItem.Add("name", item.Name);
        newItem.Add("value", item.Value);    
    }
    if (!items.Contains(newItem, new EqualityComparer()) items.Add(newItem);
}
```

Thus there is no need to create a new implementation of `Dictionary`.